# Render specific frames with opengl via python

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

When I run the following script, current_frame is set AFTER the render.opengl():

```
bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 234
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_current = 234
bpy.ops.render.opengl(view_context=False)
```

If I run the script again, the correct frame is rendered.
How can I force the frame_current to be applied before the render?

(A solution without using an operator is also welcome, as I understand that ops are more for user interaction that for scripts and are therefor very dependent on the correct context.)

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(234)` to change the frame before rendering. See this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8387/how-to-get-keyframe-data-from-python

Answer (score 11):

You have to call [Scene.frame_set()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_set) instead of setting the property [Scene.frame_current](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.frame_current):

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(234)
```

Only `frame_set()` updates animation data correctly. `frame_current` is mostly intended for reading access to determine the current frame.

---

Following example renders frame `0`, `230`, `99` and writes them to the disk as `test_000.png`, `test_099.png` and `test_230.png`.

```
import bpy
import os

# format integer with leading zeros
def formatNumbers(number, length):
    return '_%0*d' % (length, number)

# get the scene
scn = bpy.context.scene

# get the output path
output_path = scn.render.filepath

# set filename
filename = "test"

# set render frames
render_frames = [0, 230, 99]

# iterate through render frames
for f in render_frames:
    # set the frame
    scn.frame_set(f)
    # set filepath
    scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(
            output_path,
            filename + formatNumbers(f, 3) + ".jpg",
            )
    # render opengl
    bpy.ops.render.opengl(write_still=True)

# reset internal filepath
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
```

**Note:** `.jpg` is only a placeholder and will be overwritten by the settings in the render panel.

Comment: Might be better to write a real answer that's helpfull for others too?

Comment: I added some bits, feel free to improve it.

Comment: @CoDEmanX really nice, will add my example to it, great teamwork :)