# opengl flat shading in blender

Tags: rendering, opengl

i'm trying to render my scene from a script. i've got some objects with materials that are Shadeless, and when rendering with the blender renderer in my script, they show up as expected: no shading. if i use the opengl renderer from my script, they do not. even if i delete the light, the objects show up with shading.

i tried using bgl.glShadeModel() in my script to no success, though that didn't make much sense to me anyway.

is there a way to specify that the opengl renderer should render the same way as the blender render, using the material's Shadeless property correctly? note that the material is pretty simple: a color, and that is being picked up properly.

Comment: Do you have GLSL enabled?

Comment: For a better understanding, please add an image of the desired shader (blender renderer). For the rendering procedure see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27640/3710